# Gather multiple kinects v2 data in one computer

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect, lan, kinect-v2

I would like to use three kinects v2 running on three computers and then gather their data in one computer (real time 3d reconstruction using unity3d). Is it possible to do so and how ? Thank you.

Comment: I do not know if I answered your question fully. Is there anything I missed or that you would like elaborated on?

Answer (score 3):

So what you're asking is very do-able, it just takes a lot of work.

For reference I'm referring to the frames of the 3D point cloud gathered by the kinect as your image.

All you need is to set up a program on each of your kinect-computers that runs them as a client. With the other computer you can run that as a server and have the clients sending packets of images with some other data attached.
The data you'll need at a minimum will be angle and position from 'origin'.
For this to work properly you need to be able to reference the data in all your kinects to each other. The easiest way to do this is to have a known point and measure the distance from that point and angle the kinects are facing vs North and sea level.

Once you have all that data you can take each image from each computer and rotate the bit clouds using trigonometry, then combine all the data. Combing the data is something you'll have to play with as there are loads of different ways to do it and it will depend on your application.